# The point with Polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polar-coordinates

In spivak's calculus there is a section named Appendix 3 about polar coordinates which somewhere says that , it always make sense to talk about "the point with polar coordinates " , instead of "the polar coordinates "of a given point, and draws a graphs which say that if P is a point in third quadrant with polar coordinates  (r,¤) then it  has also polar coordinates  (-r,●) where  ¤ and ● represents angles made by P in 1st & 3rd quadrants counter clockwise. So my query is that how's that r could be negative & put some more light on this topic that how different convention of writing a point in polar coordinates  means the same.

Comment: for example $2i=2e^{i\pi/2}=-2e^{-i\pi/2}$

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates we may use negative values for $r$ when it is more convenient.

For example if you wish to graph the polar function $$r=2-3\cos(\theta)$$ and you are given that $$0\le\theta \le \pi/2$$ you need to give values for $\theta$ and find values for $r$

If you start with $\theta =0$ you get $r=-1$ which is negative. The  polar point $(-1,0)$ has also polar coordinates of $(1,\pi )$, but you are told to go with $0 \le\theta \le\pi/2$ thus $\pi$ is not allowed.

Comment: Yes it helped. Thanks .

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Comment: But what if \pi is included in the domain?

Comment: Then you get  $r=2+3=5$ so the point will be $(5, \pi)$